# Uniform convergence in finite dimensional subspace of $C[0,1]$.

Tags: calculus, uniform-convergence

> Let $X\subset C[0,1]$ be a finite dimensional linear subspace of real-valued continuous functions on $[0,1]$. Show that, for a sequence of functions $\{f_k\}_{k\geq 1}\subset X$, if it converges pointwise, it converges uniformly.

How to use the  finite dimensional linear subspace?

Comment: Take  a basis $(g_i)$. The coeffcients in $\sum c_ig_i$ are continuous functions on this space.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Let $f_n=\sum_k c_{kn}(x)g_k$, How to show that $c_{kn}(x)$ is continuous.

Comment: Any linear map on a  finite dimensional normed vector space is continuous.